# How do i resolve this ambiguous Azure error?

Tags: bash, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, runcommand

I am using run commands to execute bash scripts via the Azure CLI bash scripts in RHEL 7 VM.

I am getting an error when there is a snippet of the run command:

```
   az vm run-command invoke --name ${THIS_VM_NAME} \
            --command-id RunShellScript \
            --resource-group ${RSC_GRP_NAME} \
            --query "output[].message | join('\n\n', @)" \
            --scripts "
cat > /etc/init.d/parity <<'EOF'
${INIT_D_PARITY}
exit 0
EOF

chmod +x /etc/init.d/parity

service parity restart

sleep 5

ls -la /var/log/parity.err
ls -la /var/log/parity.log
ls -la /var/log/parity.node.log

echo '_____________________________________________'
echo 'Parity Error Log:'
tail -n 5 /var/log/parity.err
echo '_____________________________________________'

ls -la /usr/libs/libssl*

parity -v

cat /var/log/parity.node.log | grep -oEi '(enode.*@)' | tail -n 1 | sed 's/enode:\/\///' | sed 's/@.*//' > /etc/parity/enode.pub

ls -la /etc/init.d/parity
ls -la /etc/parity/enode.pub

cat /etc/parity/enode.pub
echo 'Parity is Up an running \o/'
"
```

Here is the error message:

> In function join(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of:
>   ['array-string'], received: "null" Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Run bash only with `join('\n\n', @)` and check what values should be there and what value contains `@` here.

Comment: That `cat | grep | awk | sed` pipeline should probably be refactored.  See [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT the new version of the cli uses `value` not output. This is what was breaking it

Comment: @Data_Kid If you mean the command should be `value[].message | join('\n\n', @)`?

Comment: precisely. @CharlesXu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

The join() is a function of JMESPath that a query language for JSON. Here is an easy example:

Array:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}
```

Query code:

```
locations[?state == 'WA'].name | sort(@) | {WashingtonCities: join(', ', @)}
```

Result:

```
{
  "WashingtonCities": "Bellevue, Olympia, Seattle"
}
```

For your issue, you can get the details from this [link](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#join). I think if the output is an array then the function join() will work well. If not, the error as same as you got will come.